# Compiling native android library with multiple c files using ndk build errors * No rule to make target

Tags: android, c, compilation, android-ndk

I am having an issue compiling a shared C library into a .so for android.  I've copied all the .c and .h files into the jni folder.  I posted a screenshot below to show the contents of the `Android.mk` file as well as the folder hierarchy.

[image: Android.mk and Folder contents]

below is the output of `ndk-build` run in the project root folder *NTRUMLS*

```
[kenway@jackdaw NTRUMLS]$ ndk-build
make: *** No rule to make target '/media/bigdata/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/crypto_hash_sha512.c', needed by 'obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ntrumls/crypto_hash_sha512.o'.  Stop.
```

i checked for spaces and typo's.  here's the contents of my Android.mk copied directly below.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_MODULE := libntrumls
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := crypto_hash_sha512.c \
                crypto_stream.c \
                convert.c \
                randombytes.c \
                fastrandombytes.c \
                pack.c \
                pol.c \
                params.c \
                pqntrusign.c \
                shred.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```

to be the first statement of your **Android.mk** script.

Comment: thank you! i moved it to the top of the file and it compiled!

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm


LOCAL_MODULE := libntrumls
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Main_M1_play.cpp

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```